# How to exit looping dialog boxes by pressing a key?

Tags: java

I'm kind of new to Java and I'm working on a program with multiple nested loops that display JOPtionPane.showMessageDialog boxes. I want to be able to press a key to stop the whole process(preferably ESCAPE, but if that won't work, I could use any key that will). To test out the idea, I've tried making a simple infinite loop and tried to implement a KeyListener, but I don't know if I'm on the right track. And advice or an example or adding to my code would be so helpful.(I took out all my previously problematic code for the KeyListener)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DBinfinite
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;

        while (x >= 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x);
            x++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if you ar using the `JOptionPane`'s `showXXX()` convienience methods. The dialogs are not exposed and cannot be modified. If you want addition behavior you will have to create your own dialogs and code the logic yourself.